# System.ArgumentException: Get Method not found for 'XXXXXXX' at System.Reflection.MonoPropert

Tags: c#, xamarin, reflection, xamarin.ios

whenever am trying to access the value of a property through `reflection` am getting a error like

> "System.ArgumentException: Get Method not found for 'XXXX' at
>   System.Reflection.MonoProperty.Get"

. Am using Xamarin studio version 6.3 and property also declared as `public` only.

Model:

```
using System;
namespace XXXX.Core
{
    public class ManufacturingParameters
    {
        public ManufacturingParameters()
        {
        }

        private int oemCode;
        public int OEMCode
        {
            get { return oemCode; }
            set { oemCode = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Ex Code:

```
ValueString = deviceInfoContentVC.devInfo.manufacturingParameters.GetType().GetProperty(ParamSchema.Key).GetValue(deviceInfoContentVC.devInfo.manufacturingParameters).ToString();
```

The above code works perfectly in Visual studio but not in xamarin studio.

But I can access the same property through below code:

```
ValueString = deviceInfoContentVC.devInfo.manufacturingParameters.oemCode.ToString();
```

Since i wanted to access it dynamically i need `reflection` kind of mechanism.

Is there any alternative solution/fix for this?

Thank You.

Comment: suggest separate the statement with reflection to several shorter ones so you can debug in which one error occurs.

Comment: Shouldn't you go for the `OEMCode` (public property) instead of the `oemCode` (private field). Also what is `ParamSchema.Key`

Comment: @Lei Yang am getting error at GetValue()

Comment: @Icepickle ParamSchema.Key is "OEMCode"

Comment: why do you need sytax like that? need more context(actual what you want to do)

Comment: @Lei Yang I want to fetch the property value from the model using string like using "OEMCode" i need to fetch the value of corresponding property from the model

Comment: suggest replace variable like `deviceInfoContentVC.devInfo.manufacturingParameters` to some **const** string(or some object array), just for debugging yourself and for us to better understand the question.

Comment: ValueString = ManufacturingParameters.GetType().GetProperty("OEMCode").GetValue(ManufacturingParameters).ToString();

Comment: also change `ManufacturingP‌​arameters` to const, and edit your question instead of put in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this issue and here is the solution I found.

It Was the linker stripping it away. I had changed the Linker Behaviour to "Link Framework SDK's Only" from "Link All" under iOS project's settings, and under the Build heading.

Now its works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

On android build change:
Project Settings > Player > Optimisation > Managed Stripping Level - set it to "Minimal" (will not remove any user-written code).

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeStripping.html